# c++ Trouble assigning pointer to object via a pointer to that object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I'm having trouble assigning a pointer to an object, by assigning it to another pointer that is pointing to that object. Here's my code:

In Map.h:

```
using namespace std;
class Map;
Map *CurrentMap;
class Map
{
    private:
        Map *NM, *EM, *SM, *WM;
        string NMe, EMe, SMe, WMe;
    public:
        void Initialize(Map N, Map E, Map S, Map W, string MeN, string MeE, string MeS, string MeW)
        {
            NM = &N; EM = &E; SM = &S; WM = &W;
            NMe = MeN; EMe = MeE; SMe = MeS; WMe = MeW;
        }

        void GoNorth()
        {
            cout << NMe << endl;
            CurrentMap = NM;  //This is the problem, this is where it crashes my program
        }

        void GoEast()
        {
            cout << EMe << endl;
            CurrentMap = EM;
        }

        void GoSouth()
        {
            cout << SMe << endl;
            CurrentMap = SM;
        }

        void GoWest()
        {
            cout << WMe << endl;
            CurrentMap = WM;
        }
};
```

In Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Map.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Map A,B,C,D,E,F;
    A.Initialize(B,C,D,E,"Towards B","Towards C","Towards D","Towards E");
    B.Initialize(D,F,A,F,"Towards D","Towards F","Towards A","Towards F");
    C.Initialize(F,E,F,A,"Towards F","Towards E","Towards F","Towards A");
    D.Initialize(A,F,B,F,"Towards A","Towards F","Towards B","Towards F");
    E.Initialize(F,A,F,C,"Towards F","Towards A","Towards F","Towards C");
    F.Initialize(A,A,A,A,"Towards A","Towards A","Towards A","Towards A");
    CurrentMap = &A;

    CurrentMap->GoNorth();
    CurrentMap->GoNorth();
    CurrentMap->GoNorth();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output from the above code is:

```
    Towards B
    Towards D
    Towards A
```

But what I get is:

```
    Towards B
    //Crash, Unhandled Exception: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing by value and with those values
you are creating temporary copies and taking the address of them,
which of course will be invalid as soon as they go out of scope.

Change the signature of Initialize to take pointers or references.

```
`void Initialize(Map *N, Map *E, Map *S, Map *W, string MeN, string MeE, string MeS, string MeW);`
```

And take the addresses when initializing.

```
`A.Initialize(&B, &C, &D, &E,"Towards B","Towards C","Towards D","Towards E");`
```

Comment: DUDE! Thanks so much, works like a charm! This has been bugging me for AGES. Now it works without problems :D

Comment: That being said tho, there is a glaring design issue here and that is who has ownership of the objects? is map supposed to have shared ownership? sole-ownership? shared_ptr and unique_ptr would be alot clearer and less brittle. You should only be taking references if you can guarantee the object you are referencing will live longer than the object that holds the reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, you are assigning your pointers to passed-by-value arguments, which means that as soon as Initialize() returns, your class's pointers are now pointing at objects that no longer exist.

```
    void Initialize(Map N, Map E, Map S, Map W, string MeN, string MeE, string MeS, string MeW)
    {
        NM = &N; EM = &E; SM = &S; WM = &W;
        NMe = MeN; EMe = MeE; SMe = MeS; WMe = MeW;
    }
```

If you really want your class to hold pointers to the objects that you declared in main(), you'll need to do pass-by-reference instead:

```
    void Initialize(Map & N, Map & E, Map & S, Map & W, string MeN, string MeE, string MeS, string MeW)
    {
        NM = &N; EM = &E; SM = &S; WM = &W;
        NMe = MeN; EMe = MeE; SMe = MeS; WMe = MeW;
    }
```

... or you could change Initialize() to accept pointer arguments (e.g. Map *) instead.  But you might want to reconsider your design, and just hold copies of the objects instead of pointers to objects declared elsewhere.  Doing it that way will be less fragile, so you'll be less likely to make a mistake that causes your program to crash.